# Why += doesn't work with Lists?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Although I know that there are more idomatic ways of doing this, why doesn't this code work? (Mostly, why doesn't the first attempt at just `x += 2` work.) Are these quite peculiar looking (for a newcomer to Scala at least) error messages some `implicit def` magic not working right?

```
scala> var x: List[Int] = List(1)
x: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> x += 2
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: String
       x += 2
            ^

scala> x += "2"
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String
 required: List[Int]
       x += "2"
         ^

scala> x += List(2)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: String
       x += List(2)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator.

To append to a collection you should use `:+` and not `+`.  This is because of problems caused when trying to mirror Java's behaviour with the use of `+` for concatenating to Strings.

```
scala> var x: List[Int] = List(1)
x: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> x :+= 2

scala> x
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

You can also use `+:` if you want to prepend.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) in the Scala API. Methods for adding an element to a list are:

```
2 +: x

x :+ 2

2 :: x
```